# Laravel 5.5 eloquent one-to-many not work using get()

Tags: php, laravel

I have `one to many` relationships and need to show using where conditions.

When I use `findOrFail()` it's working as well.

```
$foo = Model::findOrFail(1);
```

on my template blade

```
@foreach($foo->bars as $index=>$bar)

   {{ $bar->name }}

@endforeach
```

on my code above, it's working. but the reference to an `id`, that's not what I need.

I need it using where conditions. like this:

```
$foo = Model::where('conditon', 1)->get();
```

then I call it on my blade template with

```
@foreach($foo->bars as $index=>$bar)

   {{ $bar->name }}

@endforeach
```

then I get an error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Property [bars] does not exist on this collection instance.

It seems after `get()` I cannot call `child` with `$foo->bars`

How do you get this to work?

Comment: get() will return a collection of $foos, not a model, which findOrFail does return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The findOrFail() method returns an instance of the "Model".
The get() method returns a collection of instances of the "Model" even if there is only one result.

if you want just one result, use first() instead of get().

```
$foo = Model::where('conditon', 1)->first();
```

then in the blade template do

```
@if($foo)
    @foreach($foo->bars as $index=>$bar)

       {{ $bar->name }}

    @endforeach
@endif
```

if you need multiple results, do another foreach().

```
@foreach($foo as $oneFoo)

    @foreach($oneFoo->bars as $index=>$bar)

        {{ $bar->name }}

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

if you are going with the "multiple" solution, i suggest you name your variable "foos".

```
$foos = Model::where('conditon', 1)->get();
```

and so

```
@foreach($foos as $foo)

    @foreach($foo->bars as $index=>$bar)

        {{ $bar->name }}

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: this is work but . when i use `count()` its counted all the record.

Comment: can you write me where you did the count ?

Comment: `$foo = Model::where('conditon', 1)->first();`  then I use count to check its exist or not on my blade template `$foo->count()` its return all the record counted, when use `get()` its return 1

Comment: I just got `easy` solution than this. thank you for your answer, appreciate it!

Comment: use the $foo = Model::where('conditon', 1)->first(); and in the blade template use @if($foo) as i edited in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `->first()` instead of `->get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `->get()` retrieve multiple results which fit the query criteria.

You can either loop through `$foo` results or use `->first()` to retreive the first query match.

Comment: when use `first()` then use `count()` its return all the record counted. I expected return number that has condition `1`